# new line in html textarea

Tags: html, django-templates

Hi there I have a form in my html on my django project. I want that the users can enter a text and when they press enter or paste a text with empty lines they should be shown. For example if you enter:

Hi there,

my name is ellen

they should not see

Hi there, my name is ellen.

However in my code the text is displayed as the wrong example.
Here is my html file. Thanks in advance.

html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 10000;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' karakter hakkın kaldı.');

    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' karakter hakkın kaldı.');
    });
});
</script>
<div class="container">
<br>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">{{post.post}} </h1>
<p style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">{{post.created_on}}</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Yorum At</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
{% for i in commentmodel_list%}
<h4 >{{i.comment}}</h4>
{% if i.author_security == user%}
<a style="float:right;color:red;" href="{% url 'forum:delete' slug=post.slug comment_id=i.id %}?next={{ request.path }}" ><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
{% endif %}
{% if i.author is none %}
<p style="font-size:small;">Anonim | {{i.created_on}}</p>
{% else%}
<p style="font-size:small;"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="#">@{{i.author}}</a> | {{i.created_on}}</p>
{% endif %}

<hr>
<br>
{% endfor %}
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
       {%if user.is_authenticated%}
             <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
                 {% csrf_token %}
         <label for="comment">Yorum:</label>
         <br>
         <textarea id="textarea" maxlength="10000"name="comment" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
         <div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
                 <br>
                 <br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="anonn" id="anonn">
                 <label for="anonn">Anonim olarak yorum atmak için Tıkla!</label>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Paylaş</button>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                 </div>
             </form>
       {%else%}
       <p style="text-align:center;">Yorum atmak için <a style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;" href="{% url 'account:login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Giriş</a> yapmalısın.</p>
       {% endif %}
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#textarea').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart) + "" + "\n" + this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd, this.value.length);
  }
});
</script>



{% endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use *linebreaks* tag

```
<div>{{ var_name|linebreaks }}</div>
```